# Visual Studio 2010 stopped Formatting my javascript...?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

So CTRL E + D auto formats my pages and I love it!

Usually, if I have an error in my code, the formatting no longer works...I get that.

But I have no errors in my javascript (verified by IE and Chrome) and it suddenly quit formatting...

Any ideas?

Comment: You may have an error which is ignored by IE and Chrome but fails JScript validation in VS (missing semicolons, an extra parenthesis, etc.). Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Comment: I've rebooted my whole system twice.

Comment: Is it a Web *site* or a Web *Application* project? Is JScript validation disabled? You could try running your JavaScript through JSLint or another validation tool.

Comment: Cory - why dont you take your first suggestion and offer it as an answer so I can credit you for it!  It was actually much easier to find than I thought... Ill explain it when I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Promoting comment to answer at OP's request:</sup>

You may have an error which is ignored by IE and Chrome but fails JScript validation in VS (missing semicolons, an extra parenthesis, etc.). Have you tried restarting Visual Studio?

Also, is it a Web site or a Web Application project? Is JScript validation disabled? You could try running your JavaScript through JSLint or another validation tool.

---

**EDIT:** According to the OP (see comment below), he had an extraneous trailing comma in a property list that was preventing auto-formatting in VS. For example:

```
var culprit = {
    property1 = "23",
    property2 = "43", // <-- Extraneous comma
};
```

Comment: JQuery - .ajax function - leave an extra comma in DATA section - see last comma below - Chrome and IE both work fine and UNFORTUNATELY don't report your issue... neither does VS (although there was a green squiggly but I didnt get an error) -- I FOUND THIS by simple starting a new js file in vs and adding sections in at a time until the formatting broke, it was much easier than I thought it would be.  Thanks Cory!

 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'WorkflowWizard.aspx,
        data: {
            'param1': true,
            'param2': 'whatever',  //THERE'S THE CULPRIT!
        },